# ASP.NET MVC4 - During an [HttpPost] Create, the object (model) that's passed in to Create(MyObj obj) is null for some reason

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, model-binding

When I click "Add Department", it takes me to `/Department/Create?contactId=1`:

[image]

Here's the "Create" view.  I fill it out, then click "Create":

[image]

Here's the code I step through once I click "Create".  Notice that the object is null:

[image]

But, "contactId" is not null.  This value is "1", as expected from the query string.  Here's my Create view:

```
@model CallCOP.Models.Department

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.dept_id)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.contact_id)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Department</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.dept)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.dept)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.dept)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.dept_phone)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.dept_phone)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.dept_phone)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

Here's my Department class:

```
namespace CallCOP.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;

    public partial class Department
    {
        public int dept_id { get; set; }
        public int contact_id { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Department")]
        public string dept { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Phone Number")]
        public string dept_phone { get; set; }

        public virtual Contact Contact { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And, here's the rendered HTML for my Create view, as per request:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Create - My ASP.NET MVC Application</title>
        <link href="/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        <link href="/Content/site.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

        <script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <div class="content-wrapper">
                <div class="float-left">
                    <p class="site-title"><a href="/">your logo here</a></p>
                </div>
                <div class="float-right">
                    <section id="login">
                       Hello, <span class="username">DOMAIN\userId</span>!
                    </section>
                    <nav>
                        <ul id="menu">
                            <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/Home/About">About</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/Home/Contact">Contact</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
        <div id="body">

            <section class="content-wrapper main-content clear-fix">


<form action="/Department/Create?contactId=1" method="post"><input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="Q2GiIaT-qLIXxW_WN0o6o_5Tt5q2W6uXx6Ax2WEliVI2BqzAWFMZ7zwW0wX_R-rESzUn8mqFBChd8NB3jrZthK3d6LmmuRZQsdVu0v8hvSd_3_FstePrKvtjPXQ3BHtp3FXuqXdpduTsv2Nwzd1VI2cE16k1sq6QgL8ghP9HmXM1" /><input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field dept_id must be a number." data-val-required="The dept_id field is required." id="dept_id" name="dept_id" type="hidden" value="" /><input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field contact_id must be a number." data-val-required="The contact_id field is required." id="contact_id" name="contact_id" type="hidden" value="" />    <fieldset>
        <legend>Department</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            <label for="dept">Department</label>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <input class="text-box single-line" id="dept" name="dept" type="text" value="" />
            <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="dept" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            <label for="dept_phone">Phone Number</label>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <input class="text-box single-line" id="dept_phone" name="dept_phone" type="text" value="" />
            <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="dept_phone" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
</form>
<div>
    <a href="/Department">Back to List</a>
</div>


            </section>
        </div>
        <footer>
            <div class="content-wrapper">
                <div class="float-left">
                    <p>&copy; 2013 - My ASP.NET MVC Application</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>

        <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>


    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>


    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have an idea of what's wrong, but, you need to show some more code.  Can you show what your model class actually looks like as well as what the rendered HTML is for the `Create` view?

Comment: @Ek0nomik, I updated my post, thank you for taking the time to look at it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing the name of the parameter in your `ActionResult`:

```
public ActionResult Create(Department dept) {
    ...
}
```

to

```
public ActionResult Create(Department department) {
    ...
}
```

The binding is getting confused with the `dept` parameter matching the name of the `dept` property on the model.

Comment: So technically could I call "dept" anything other than "dept" and it should work?

Comment: Correct.  Just avoid naming it after one of the properties within the model.  I almost always camel case my parameters with the same name as the class of the model itself.